# How to convert the audio data to CMSampleBufferRef?

Tags: audio, record

I will to recoding  audio to a video file by using AVAssetWriterInput, and the audio data is store in memory with byte array format.how can I do it?
I frind the CMAudioSampleBufferCreateWithPacketDescriptions function meet my request, any one has the sample to use it,by using byte array audio data?